# Restore auto-increment id on rails 4 with postgresql

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, rails-migrations

I needed to make some data migration from an old website we had to the new rails one. I needed to preserve my cities ids so i created my table with id set to false and created that column manually:

```
create_table "cities", id: false, force: true do |t|
   t.integer  "id", null: false
   t.string   "name", null: false
   t.datetime "created_at"
   t.datetime "updated_at"
   t.boolean  "is_active",  default: true, null: false
   t.string   "code_che"
end

add_index "cities", ["id"], name: "index_cities_on_id", unique: true, using: :btree
```

Once I finished my migration, I wanted to be able to create new cities, for example City.create(name: 'My big city') but I get the next error:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::NotNullViolation: ERROR:  null value in column "id" violates not-null constraint
```

Crearly I made a mistake, can you help me find out where? I'm using rails 4 with postgresql gem.

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is probably a more Rails-y way to do it, but using straight SQL you need to do this.  Replace "12345" with one more than the current maximum value for 'id'.

```
CREATE SEQUENCE cities_id_seq START WITH 12345;
ALTER TABLE cities ALTER COLUMN id SET DEFAULT 'nextval(''cities_id_seq''::regclass)';
ALTER TABLE cities ALTER COLUMN id SET NOT NULL;
```

You can put this into a Rails migration like so:

```
def up
  execute %Q{
    CREATE SEQUENCE cities_id_seq START WITH 12345;
    ALTER TABLE cities ALTER COLUMN id SET DEFAULT 'nextval(''cities_id_seq''::regclass)';
    ALTER TABLE cities ALTER COLUMN id SET NOT NULL;
  }
end
```

P.S.  Next time you can leave the sequence creation to rails and when you migrate the data just set the id value directly.  Then when you're done it's a simple matter of updating the sequences next value.

Comment: Thanks man, it worked like a charm. I just had to remove the outermost  single quotes in the second line. Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

First, kill off your existing `cities` table (assuming you haven't added any new data to it of course). Then create `cities` in the normal fashion:

```
create_table "cities", force: true do |t|
   t.string   "name", null: false
   t.datetime "created_at"
   t.datetime "updated_at"
   t.boolean  "is_active",  default: true, null: false
   t.string   "code_che"
end
```

That will give you a normal `cities` table complete with an `id` as the primary key and the `id` will be given values from a sequence.

Next import the existing data. This will give you a bunch of `id` values that the sequence behind `cities.id` doesn't know about so you'll get problems if you try to insert new cities. This is easy to fix using PostgreSQL's [`setval` function](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-sequence.html) to adjust the sequence with a bit of SQL in a migration:

```
execute(%q{
  select setval('cities_id_seq', (select max(id) from cities))
})
```

When you let Rails create the `id` PK for the table, it will use a [`serial`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-numeric.html#DATATYPE-SERIAL) column for `id`. A `serial` column is, more or less, an `integer` column with a sequence to supply default values. For a table called `X`, the sequence's name will be `X_id_seq`, hence the `cities_id_seq` name above. Then you want to set the current value for the sequence to the maximum existing `cities.id` value so that the *next* value from the sequence will be one more than that maximum.